# Vector containing GADT

Tags: haskell, vector, existential-type, gadt, data-kinds

I'm just learning everything I can about ExistentialQuantification and GADTs and KindSignatures, etc. And to do that I try to come up with some small programs which help me to understand everything better.

Now I have this small snippet (which actually compiles, so you can try it on your own, requires *vector* and *mtl* packages) and would like to know whether it is at all possible to do what I am trying to accomplish or guide me to how to make it work

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data MenuItem = ListS | ActionS | SliderS

data MenuItemReference (a :: MenuItem) (n :: *) where
       MenuListSReference :: Int -> MenuItemReference ListS Int
       MenuActionSReference :: Int -> MenuItemReference ActionS Int
       MenuSliderSReference :: Int -> MenuItemReference SliderS Int

data MyState = MyState { vec :: forall a. V.Vector (MenuItemReference a Int) }

newMyState :: MyState
newMyState = MyState { vec = V.empty }

listRef :: MenuItemReference ListS Int
listRef = MenuListSReference 5

actionRef :: MenuItemReference ActionS Int
actionRef = MenuActionSReference 3

myComputation :: State MyState ()
myComputation = do
    addItem listRef
    addItem actionRef
    return ()

addItem :: forall a. MenuItemReference a Int -> State MyState ()
addItem menuItemRef = do
    s <- get
    put (s { vec = (vec s) `V.snoc` menuItemRef })

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ evalState myComputation newMyState
```

As you can see I'm trying to get a Vector of MenuItemReferences in it... What is it that I'm doing wrong because with what I have at the moment I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        addItem :: MenuItemReference a Int -> State MyState ()
      at Main.hs:34:19
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: V.Vector (MenuItemReference a1 Int)
       at Main.hs:37:10
Expected type: MenuItemReference a1 Int
  Actual type: MenuItemReference a Int
Relevant bindings include
  menuItemRef :: MenuItemReference a Int (bound at Main.hs:35:9)
  addItem :: MenuItemReference a Int -> State MyState ()
    (bound at Main.hs:35:1)
In the second argument of ‘V.snoc’, namely ‘menuItemRef’
In the ‘vec’ field of a record
```

Could someone explain what is the reason behind the error and how I could approach (if at all possible) the thing I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well the problem that I see is that you quantified the Vector, not the inside of it; consider `forall a. [a]` vs `[forall a. a]`. That being said, the obvious change produces `Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: ... GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism` which I have no idea how to tackle, tbh. But then again, your `MenuItemReference` type seems a bit weird - `a` looks like a phantom type but I've no idea what it's supposed to do.

Comment: This is a stripped down example just to show the problem. The `MenuItemReference` should be used to grab the correct item from other collections in my state. So `MenuItemReference ListS Int` will grab something from `menuListItems`, `MenuItemReferences ActionS Int` will grab something from `menuActionItems` and so on (`menuListItems` and `menuActionItems` are in `MyState` and they are *Vectors* of different data types)

Comment: Oh... my... god... Thank you Bartek! I actually didn't see that (I mean duplication). You are correct, this is a useless duplication and the constructors themselves give enough information for me. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: Yeah this isn't very straighforward, I backed out of that comment because I thought you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just

```
data MenuItemReference = 
    MenuListSReference Int | 
    MenuActionSReference Int | 
    MenuSliderSReference Int
```

then?

The constructor used already annotates the value. You don't need to inject the phantom type, because the information is already there.

Besides, doing so would require enabling GHC ([`{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Impredicative_types)) to actually support [*impredicative polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Impredicative_polymorphism) to construct `Vector [forall a. MenuItemReference a Int]` and use it polymorphically. While it does support that, the support has been described as "fragile at best and broken at worst".

As a side note [this nice blog post](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2014-12-23-impredicative.html) explains how we can get rid of impredicative types, using `newtype`s and `RankNTypes` instead. This does require you to introduce a layer of `newtype`, however.